# add new key/value to each object inside a huge deeply nested objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have a huge object, with almost 50k lines.
I need to add in each object new key with the current path of the node

Example:

```js
let obj = {
  "title": "RESSONÂNCIA MAGNÉTICA DA COLUNA LOMBAR",
  "data": [{
    "title": "Método:",
    "data": [{
        "title": "Procedimento 1",
        "data": [{
            "title": "CONTRASTE"
          },
          {
            "title": "CONTRASTE 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Procedimento 2",
        "data": [{
            "title": "CONTRASTE 3"
          },
          {
            "title": "CONTRASTE 4"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

And I need to change my object to return this:

```js
obj = {
  "path": "$",
  "title": "RESSONÂNCIA MAGNÉTICA DA COLUNA LOMBAR",
  "data": [{
    "path": "$.data.0",
    "title": "Método:",
    "data": [{
        "path": "$.data.0.data.0",
        "title": "Procedimento 1",
        "data": [{
            "path": "$.data.0.data.0.data.0",
            "title": "CONTRASTE"
          },
          {
            "path": "$.data.0.data.0.data.1",
            "title": "CONTRASTE 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "path": "$.data.0.data.1",
        "title": "Procedimento 2",
        "data": [{
            "path": "$.data.0.data.1.data.0",
            "title": "CONTRASTE 3"
          },
          {
            "path": "$.data.0.data.1.data.1",
            "title": "CONTRASTE 4"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

If you notice, i added the key **path** inside each object for key **data**, with the current path of the node. This is what I need.

All my object are much bigger then this example, with much more nested objects

Comment: Where is the code you have written that attempts to do this?

Comment: there is no code, i have no idea how to do it, i only know how the result must be @kmoser

Comment: I recommend you write a recursive function that updates the path field while traversing the data arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performant version in case you have to deal with large files

```js
const data = {
  "title": "RESSONÂNCIA MAGNÉTICA DA COLUNA LOMBAR",
  "data": [{
    "title": "Método:",
    "data": [{
        "title": "Procedimento 1",
        "data": [{
            "title": "CONTRASTE"
          },
          {
            "title": "CONTRASTE 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Procedimento 2",
        "data": [{
            "title": "CONTRASTE 3"
          },
          {
            "title": "CONTRASTE 4"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }]
}

function PathUpdate(data, path) {
  data.path = path;
  const nd = data.data;
  if (nd == null) return;
  for (let i = 0; i < nd.length; i++) {
    PathUpdate(nd[i], `${path}.data.${i}`);
  }
}
console.log("before", { data });
PathUpdate(data, "$");
console.log("after", { data });
```

Comment: It also worked (for my project that I know all key data are the one I have to iterate), and it really has better performance. Super thanks

Comment: This in my case has better performance, that's why i selected it as accepted answer, but if other people are looking for answers here, @Prime answer might have a better fit

Comment: Performance comparison on object with 22k lines: `iterate all keys: 13.032958984375 ms` VS `iterate only data key: 0.7099609375 ms`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = {
  title: "RESSONÂNCIA MAGNÉTICA DA COLUNA LOMBAR",
  type: "template",
  data: [
    {
      title: "Método:",
      type: "top-level-component",
      data: [
        {
          title: "Procedimento",
          type: "navigation",
          normal: "CONTRASTE",
          checked: true,
          data: [
            {
              type: "single-selection",
              title: "CONTRASTE",
            },
            {
              type: "single-selection",
              title: "CONTRASTE 2",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          title: "Procedimento 2",
          type: "navigation",
          normal: "CONTRASTE",
          checked: false,
          data: [
            {
              type: "single-selection",
              title: "CONTRASTE 3",
            },
            {
              type: "single-selection",
              title: "CONTRASTE 4",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
function addPathToObj(obj, path) {
  obj.path = path;
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      value.forEach((item, index) => {
        addPathToObj(item, `${path}.data.${index}`);
      });
    }
  }
}
addPathToObj(data, "$");
console.log(data);
```

Comment: with a small object it worked, will test in real scenario, with huge object, but I really appreciate it

Comment: IT WORKED, just needed to check if the current item is an object before iterate again `if (typeof item === 'object')`